# Update the text of a label using Centura/SQLWindows32

Tags: guptateamdeveloper, centura

Is there any function to update the text of a label in Centura/SQLWindows32?

Comment: For which version?

Answer (score 1):

There's another solution if you have the label in front of an input object (i.e. a data field).
Use `SalSetWindowLabelText()` function for changing a label's text.

Example: `Call SalSetWindowLabelText(dfInput,'YourText')`.

If you have a "standalone" label, then you no other way than the ones described by GuptaSteve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running v6 or above you can treat Background text as if it were a standard object , so set the text directly using its name : Call SalSetWindowText( bkgdTextName , 'Test' )

If prior to v6 , 
`On SAM_AppStartUp
• Set bStaticsAsWindows = TRUE`

then find its handle :

•    Set hWndBkgdMyLabel = VisWinGetHandle( hWnd, 'bkgdTextName', TYPE_BkgdText )

then set text using its handle:

• Call SalSetWindowText( hWndBkgdMyLabel, 'This is the label I really needed' )

Sometimes it's necessary to force repaint of the label

• Call SalUpdateWindow( hWndBkgdMyLabel )

OR

You can the Handle by placing the Label directly before any associated object ( e.g. a DataField ) in the Outline, then :

•    Set hWndBkgdMyLabel = SalGetWindowLabel(hWndItem).

It retrieves the handle to the label attached to a button or a data field , so you can then use :

• Call SalSetWindowText( hWndBkgdMyLabel, 'This is the label I really needed' )

Note: bStaticsAsWindows must be TRUE for these last two to work if you are prior to v6